# Send approval request mail to non-salesforce user

Tags: approval-process

Is it possible to send the approval request mail to Non-salesforce users via Standard approval process?

I think by Apex we can send the approval request mail, but then how the approver will approve/reject it , if that User don't have any access in Salesforce.

Please help on this.
I've already researched a lot on this.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't currently possible using approval processes. There is an outstanding Idea here that you can vote on to help get it prioritised:

[Non Salesforce user as approver in Approval Process](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdagjUAB/non-salesforce-user-as-approver-in-approval-process)